# mysql - best way to store multiple values

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to create a question bank to help students access material during the pandemic.

I want to be able to classify each question so that students can go and search for specific topics at ease, and I am planning to store question-specific data in a table.

However, I'm finding it a bit difficult on the best way to store question specific data in a table.

For example, a probability question can be associated with multiple tags eg 'independence', 'mutually exclusive', 'tree diagram', but I can't have a variable number of tags in a single cell. And it is not possible to have an infinite number of columns in a given row.

Or maybe I am incorrect, is it possible to store an array of such tags in a single cell in MySQL? Does anyone have any more effective solutions?

Comment: you create a relationship tablewith the colun question and another to the categorie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you need have a many to many relationship and need three tables:

```
question table
    QuestionId, QuestionText
    1.        Is Corona contagious?
    2         Malaria medication
    3.        Flue medication

tag table
    TagId, TagText
     1         Contagious
     2         Virus
     3.        Medication

question_tag table
    QuestionId, TagId
       1                   1
       1.                  2
       2.                  3
       3.                  2
       3.                  3
```

Comment: @BenDerby Vote up, then.

Comment: Thanks :-) :-) :-)

Comment: I also want each student to know if they have seen a question before. Is this possible without creating a table for each student?

Comment: You need an extra table named question_seen with two columns: studentid, QuestionId. Insert a row for each student that had seen a question.